# How to delegate contacts in Google Admin SDK in Python

Tags: python, google-admin-sdk

I'm trying to delegate my Google contacts (not GMail) to another account (same Workspace). [People API](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest) does not have the option to delegate contacts so I tried [Google Admin SDK - Contact Delegation API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/contact-delegation/guides). However, I can't find a way to build the resource like other APIs.

How can I create the resource and then delegate my contacts? And what is the scope I need to allow for the credentials to work?

For other APIs, I use this code :

```py
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
# Load client_config
# Define scopes to autorize like -> scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user']
# Get the credentials into the creds variable

admin_service = build('admin', 'directory_v1', credentials=creds)

# use admin_service to create/update users in the workspace
```

My end goal is to use a service account with delegated access to impersonnate users and automatically delegate gmail and contacts. I've been able to get the gmail delegation to work, but not the contacts delegation.

I'm fairly new with Google APIs so I may have overlooked something in the documentation.

Comment: [This issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/185117586) seems to refer to what you are asking. Remember to click the white star (☆) on the top left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue has been closed. It was not intended to have a discovery file, thus the clients cannot use it to generate the required methods. What you need to do is to make the calls to the REST API directly. Just remember to add the OAuth token on the headers.